# How to separate Entry and Image using Grid within a Frame?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm making an `Entry` that has an `Image` on the right inside it.

The problem I have is that the text is placed behind the `Image`, what I want to do is that the text is cut off when it reaches the `Image`, separate the entry from the `Image`. I am using a `Frame` and inside it, a `Grid`. I have tried to put right margin to `Entry` but the `Image` is scrolling out. To do the `Entry` I am using the NuGet: [Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material/)

[image]

This is my code:

```html
<StackLayout>
    <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" HasShadow="False">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Entry
                        x:Name="entrycontrol"
                        BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference ValidateView}, Path=BGColor}"
                        HeightRequest="60"
                        Visual="Material"
                        WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference ValidateView}, Path=Width}" />
            <Image
                        x:Name="ImageRight"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="0,0,5,0"
                        HeightRequest="25"
                        HorizontalOptions="End" />
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

The `Source` of the `Image` I establish it in the code behind.

Comment: You need it inside your entry or you are ok if it is beside it?

Comment: It is not really necessary but I would like to do it as if it were on top of the entry, I like it more visually. If it is not possible it serves me the other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you are overlaying your `Image` on top of the `Entry` control. You need to specify a `Grid.Column="1"` so it uses the right hand column. A detailed explanation of how a `Grid` layout works can be found [on Microsofts site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#rows-and-columns)

I would suggest that you do not need to bind the `WidthRequest` property for the `Entry` control. Plus I would swap your column definitions around. `Auto` means the column will grow in size, `*` means it will stretch to a size based on what other columns have been defined.

To summarise you want something like:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" HasShadow="False">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> <!-- swapped -->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" /> <!-- swapped -->
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Entry x:Name="entrycontrol"
                   BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference ValidateView}, Path=BGColor}"
                   HeightRequest="60"
                   Visual="Material" />
            <Image x:Name="ImageRight"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Margin="0,0,5,0"
                   HeightRequest="25"
                   HorizontalOptions="End" />
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

Better yet if you have a fixed image size then you can simply set your `ColumnDefinition` to that size.